# Calculate Cp and Cpk from Histogram Class Counts

Tags: python, numpy, math

I can't find a way to calculate cp and cpk from my data-classes. Lets say i have 31 values in a array df[6]. Each of those values is a normalized value from the count of each classes in the range of 0.000505 - 0.000650.
Is there a way to calculate the cp without the single data values? Only with the amount of each classes?

I am not sure how important the actuall raw values are for variance, standarddeviation.

tyvm for help!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow. Acronyms are often a lot less universal than you might think, and often have many more than one possible meaning. When you ask a question completely out of context, it's often a good idea to spell words in their entirety. I'm guessing you're not trying to calculate the specific heat capacity, yet that's the first thing I think about when I read "Cp".

Comment: Also, it's pretty unclear how your "data-classes" relate to your "array df[6]". Could you please give an actual example with data, explaining what are the "single data values", what are the "amount of each classes", and what it is that you want to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

use numpy.std() method for calculating sigma value and numpy.mean() method for mean .
and use the formula Cp=(upper limit-lower limit)/(6*sigma) for Cp and Cpk=min(upper limit -mean,mean -lower limit)/(3*sigma)